# Добавление библиотек в NetBeans

Tags: javascript, netbeans

Здравствуйте!
Начала изучать JavaScript. В качестве IDE использую NetBeans 8.0.

Пытаюсь реализовать пример по [ссылке](http://xmlhttprequest.ru/). Самый первый, где описывается метод getXmlHttp()

И там есть строка:

```
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
```

Так вот. Откуда взять Mxxml2? Как подключить библиотеку, содержащую данный класс, к проекту?

Извините за глупый вопрос...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Библиотека Msxml2 теоретически должна быть установлена вместе с Windows.
Когда вы создаёте экземпляр объекта ActiveX (ActiveXObject), расширение браузера пытается найти среди зарегистрированных классов запрашиваемый вами (в данном случае Msxml2). Таким образом, объект ищется среди системных компонент, поставленных в систему. Это будет работать только в среде Windows. На машинах с Linux метод ActiveXObject работать не будет.

Comment: Я специально скачала msxml с оф. сайта. Установила.

Сейчас прохожусь отладчиком по коду. На данной строчке возникает ReferenceError: Msxml2 is not defined 

В JS надо писать что-то типа include или import?

Comment: Нет. Ничего подобного писать не нужно.

Если смотреть ваш пример (с сайта), то такая ситуация вполне допустима:

Вы же вызываете метод в конструкции try { ... } catch (...) { ... } , что предполагает возможность возникновения ошибки. При этом в catch у вас находится ещё одна подобная конструкция.

Сначала вы пытаетесь получить объект ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
Потом (если первый объект не найден) ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
И если у вас эти два объекта не доступны, то вы получаете объект через XMLHttpRequest().

Comment: Спасибо! Более-менее ясно.